# moving file from source folder to desktop

Tags: java, file, io

I am trying to move the file from the source file to automatically be saved to desktop. Essentially this is an incoming file and I want it where its visible to the user which is his/her desktop I thought I was on the right track but this code doesn't work and previous modifications does not work either can someone point me in the right direction?

```
 System.out.println("Waiting For File......");



 int filesize = 6022386;
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[filesize];
            InputStream is;

            is = connection_download.getInputStream();

            FileOutputStream fos;

            // obtain header (fileName) 
            DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(is);
            String fileName = clientData.readUTF();
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            System.out.println(fileName);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            current = bytesRead;

            do {
                bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length - current));
                if (bytesRead >= 0) {
                    current += bytesRead;
                }
            } while (bytesRead > -1);
            bos.write(mybytearray, 0, current);
            bos.flush();
            System.out.println(fileName.length());
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("DONE");
            bos.close();
            // complete file
            complete = new File(fileName);
            if (isMacOs == true) {
                downloadMac(complete);

            } else if (isWindowsOS == true) {
                downloadWindows(complete);
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(downloadFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}

public void downloadMac(File complete) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Files Will be Saved To Your Desktop");

    String OS_Path = System.getProperty("user.home");
    String savedLocation = OS_Path + "/Desktop/" + complete;
    File downloadedLocation = new File(savedLocation);
    System.out.println(downloadedLocation);

}
```

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work", do you mean it throws an error or that it's simply not doing what you want it to do?

Comment: Apologies for not being more clear, No, it simply just executes but the file is still in the project folder even after executing the code

Comment: several strange moments: 'magic number': `int filesize = 6022386;`. Before do-while loop you are reading `filesize` bytes from the stream, then you are doing something strange into the do-while loop. That's quite confusing. What exactly do you want to achieve? Your task explanation and your code do not match.

Comment: also your `downloadMac()` method does nothing to save the file. It just creates `File` class instance, it is not the same as creating a file.

Comment: Rafael, the code you are seeing just downloads a file from a Socket on the other end I just included it to show everyone so they have a foundation of what I'm trying to achieve and why; didn't mean to confuse you, All I need to do is get the File in which I downloaded and just automatically change the directory to "Desktop"